# print sqlite3_exec error message cause segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, sqlite

I use sqlite3 in C with ubuntu 14.04. 
In my process I update the db every 20 minutes.

Here is my function :

```
int update_alive_state(uint64_t ieee,bool isAlive)
{
    char *error_report = NULL;
    char sql[100];
    int result = -1;
    UpdateAliveStateSql(sql,ieee,isAlive);
    if(result = sqlite3_exec(db_event, sql, 0, 0, &error_report))
    {
        printf( "\t> CMD: %s , Error: %s\n" , sql , error_report );
        sqlite3_free(error_report);
    }

    return result;
}
```

When `sqlite3_exec()` return error and print error message, I get the segmentation fault message and the process terminated.

```
ERROR: signal 11 was trigerred:
  Fault address: 0xae703f1b
  Fault reason: address not mapped to object
Stack trace folows:
./main.bin(segmentation_fault_handler+0xd5)[0x419e9f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10330)[0x7fa386f20330]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0x1d03)[0x7fa386257943]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_printf+0x99)[0x7fa3862603d9]
./main.bin(update_alive_state+0x15d)[0x43ca78]
./main.bin(EventScanThread+0x2af)[0x442c21]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x8184)[0x7fa386f18184]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x7fa38630637d]
Executing original handler...
```

If I comment out `printf` and `sqlite3_free`, segmentation fault message would be disappeared. 
Why can I not print the error message?

### Please help me.

---

Edit:
I changed my code like this

```
if(result = sqlite3_exec(db, sql, 0, 0, &error_report))
{
    printf( "[ERR] : \t> CMD: %s , Error: %d\n" , sql , result );
    if ( error_report )
    {
        printf( "[ERR] : Error msg: %s\n", error_report );
        sqlite3_free(error_report);
    }
}
```

But I still get a segmentation fault message.

```
ERROR: signal 11 was trigerred:
  Fault address: 0x7f3dc490cf1b
  Fault reason: address not mapped to object
Stack trace folows (partial):
./main.bin(segmentation_fault_handler+0xd5)[0x419e9f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x10330)[0x7fab749ac330]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_vfprintf+0x1d03)[0x7fab73ce3943]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(_IO_printf+0x99)[0x7fab73cec3d9]
./main.bin(update_last_receive_time+0x166)[0x43d60e]
./main.bin(attr_process_attribute_report_ind+0x97)[0x4222dc]
./main.bin(si_gateway_incoming_data_handler+0xa3)[0x41b6b1]
./main.bin(tcp_socket_event_handler+0x558)[0x41c316]
./main.bin(polling_process_activity+0xde)[0x41a4e1]
./main.bin(main+0x150)[0x41a0f4]
Executing original handler...
```

The error address points to the first printf function

```
printf( "[ERR] : \t> CMD: %s , Error: %d\n" , sql , result );
```

Why? Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: And if you catch the crash in a debugger, what is the value or `error_report`? Is it perhaps a null pointer?

Comment: `sqlite3_exec` expects a double pointer to a `char` as last parameter, but you're printing it (`error_report`) as if it was a normal string.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The `sqlite3_exec` function expected a pointer to a pointer (to `char`) as a way to emulate pass-by-reference, so it can set the original pointer to point to a string. And the OP is passing the correct thing to `sqlite3_exec` (a pointer to a pointer to `char`) and since it should be a string it is printed as a string which is also correct. The problem is probably, as I mentioned in my previous comment, that there is no error message and `sqlite3_exec` leaves `error_report` as a null pointer.

Comment: Thanks  @Some programmer dude , I suppose every sqlite3_exec()  error code has error message. I will try to check if (error_report) is NULL or not.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html) states:

> If the 5th parameter to sqlite3_exec() is not NULL and no errors occur, then sqlite3_exec() sets the pointer in its 5th parameter to NULL before returning.

So it is possible that there is no error messsage at all and you should do:

```
if (result = sqlite3_exec(db_event, sql, NULL, NULL, &error_report))
{
   if (error_report)
   {
      printf( "\t> CMD: %s , Error: %s\n" , sql , error_report );
      sqlite3_free(error_report);
   }
}
```

to check if it was set to `NULL`.

---

> I changed my code like this [...]
>   But I still get segmentation fault message. [...]
>   The error address points to the first printf function:
>
> ```
> printf( "[ERR] : \t> CMD: %s , Error: %d\n" , sql , result );
> ```

If you print a character array with `%s`, printf needs a null terminated `'\0'` [C-string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string). As you dont provide your `UpdateAliveStateSql` function I can't see if the `sql` string is null terminated. To ensure that by writing a `'\0'` at the end of the buffer you could do:

```
sql[sizeof(sql) - 1] = '\0';
```

after calling the `UpdateAliveStateSql` function.

Comment: Thanks @Andre Kampling , I will try then.

Comment: @FrazierChang: I extend my answer as I saw that you edited your question. Please tell the status.